# How to collect data from Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I have for example in Twig:

```
{% customTag %}city1{% endCustomTag %}
{% customTag %}city2{% endCustomTag %}
```

or:

```
customFunction('city1')
customFunction('city2')
```

or:

```
 {{ 'city1' | customFilter }}
 {{ 'city2' | customFilter }}
```

And how to collect data from tag/function/filter for example in controller? I would like to receive in controller "city1" and "city2".

I know how to create custom tag, function and filter but is any way to get all data from these elements in controller or service?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, when the template is rendering, that means the work of your controller is already done

Comment: Hi Solook and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examplehttps://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want, but I'll give it a try. To send some data from twig template into a Controller, I would put an anchor inside your custom tags, and use `path` function, and then just add the extra info. Like:

```
#let's say your controller method where you want to send data looks like
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 */
public function testAction(Request $request) {
    $param1 = $request->get('param1'); #will receive 'city1'
    $param2 = $request->get('param2'); #will receive 'city2'
}

#twig
{% customTag %}<a href="{{ path('test', { 'param1': 'city1', 'param2': 'city2'}) }}" style="pointer-events: none;">cities</a>{% endCustomTag %}
```

Pay attention that the extra info is sent from Twig into Controller using $_GET.